# I need to decrement the cont2 variable to make a triangle

Tags: assembly

I have this code and I need to create a triangle.

I want to decrement the `cont2` variable every time `ciclo2` is executed. Can someone help me here? I can't find a place where the decrement works.

```
org 100h

;selecciona modo de vídeo
mov ah, 4FH
mov al, 02
mov bx, 13h ;modo gráfico 13H
int 10h
    mov cx, 80               ;coluna
    mov dx, 80               ;linha
    mov [cont], 30
    cicloc2:                   ;ciclo que repete a linha até fazer um quadrado
    mov [cont2], 30
            cicloc1:                    ;ciclo que cria a linha
            ;ativa um pixel
            mov ah, 0Ch               ;desenha nos pixeis do ecra
            mov al, 4                 ;determina a cor
            mov bh, 0                 ;numero de pagina grafica
            int 10h
            dec cx
            dec [cont2]
            jnz cicloc1
    mov cx, 80
    dec dx
    dec [cont2]
    dec [cont]
    jnz cicloc2

;leitura dummy para parar o ecran
mov ah, 07h
int 21h
;terminar, retorna ao SistemaOperativo
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

;DECLARAÇÕES
 cont rb 1
 cont2 rb 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the inner loop to perform one iteration less for every iteration of the outer loop? You can do that simply by initializing the inner loop counter with the value of the outer loop counter:

```
cicloc2:                   ;ciclo que repete a linha até fazer um quadrado
mov al,[cont]              
mov [cont2], al            ; cont2 will be initialized with 30, 29, 28, ...
        cicloc1:                    ;ciclo que cria a linha
        ;ativa um pixel
        mov ah, 0Ch               ;desenha nos pixeis do ecra
        mov al, 4                 ;determina a cor
        mov bh, 0                 ;numero de pagina grafica
        int 10h
        dec cx
        dec byte [cont2]
        jnz cicloc1
mov cx, 80
dec dx
dec byte [cont]
jnz cicloc2
```

Comment: Can you help me with someting else? So i need a square with 2 different colors, that make 2 triangles. I need to build another triangle on top of the other but inverted so that they can fit perfectly and make a square with 2 different colors, thanks buddy :)

Comment: Btw i need.two versions of the triangle I have noticed that this Code makes a proportional triangle but I also need one thats 100*80. And the move al command needs to be different right?